# How to get status code from result in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm using elixir and the httpc erlang module to ping a website. I can hit the website just fine but when I try to use status_code I get an argument error. I can see that the data is there in the error but I'm not sure why the error is being thrown.

What arguments am I supposed to be providing? I thought that this function only returned an integer but it looks like it's expecting something.

```
:inets.start
{:ok, result} = :httpc.request(:get, {'http://www.erlang.org', []}, [], [])
result.status_code()                                                               
** (ArgumentError) argument error
  :erlang.apply({'HTTP/1.1', 200, 'OK'}, :status_code, [])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

:httpc.request returns tuple which contains various information. The status code can be retrieved as follows.

```
:inets.start
{:ok, result} = :httpc.request(:get, {'http://www.erlang.org', []}, [], [])
{status_line, headers, body} = result
{http_version, status_code, reason_phrase} = status_line
```

The tuple structure is described as in the httpc doc. (http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#request-4)

If you want to use more elixir-style syntax (like result.status_code), one option would be to use some of the elixir libraries like [httpoison](https://hex.pm/packages/httpoison) or [httpotion](https://hex.pm/packages/httpotion).

Comment: Yes, avoid httpc. It also has some bugs when used under load. it is good if you need something quick out of the box, don't use it for actual applications.

Comment: I was using it for a quick 404 test on a list of sites. Definitely going to look into httpoison, Thanks!